# Cannot open shared object file

Tags: build, find, debian, shared-objects

I am trying to compile one of the projects found here 
USB-I2C/SPI/GPIO Interface Adapter.

I downloaded the `i2c_bridge-0.0.1-rc2.tgz` package. I installed `libusb` and that seemed to go well with no issues. I go into the `i2c_bridge-0.0.1-rc2/` directory and make. That compiles. I move into the `i2c_bridge-0.0.1-rc2/i2c` folder and make. It compiles and gives me `./i2c`. However, when I run it, it says `error while loading shared libraries: libi2cbrdg.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

The makefile in `i2c_bridge-0.0.1-rc2/i2c` has the library directory as `../`. The `libi2cbrdg.so` is in this directory (`i2c_bridge-0.0.1-rc2`). I also copied the file to `/usr/local/lib`. An `ls` of the `i2c_bridge-0.0.1-rc2/` directory is

```
i2c        i2cbrdg.d  i2cbrdg.o  libi2cbrdg.a   Makefile  tests
i2cbrdg.c  i2cbrdg.h  INSTALL    libi2cbrdg.so  README    u2c4all.sh
```

(That `i2c` is a directory)

If I `sudo ./i2c`, it still gives me the problem.

I had to take away the `-Werror` and `-noWdecrepated` (spelling?) options in all the makefiles to get them to compile, but that shouldn't affect this should it?

What else is necessary for it to find the `.so` file? If anyone can help me find out what is wrong I would be very grateful. If more information is needed I can post it.

Comment: `cannot open shared object file` is sometime solved by issuing `sudo ldconfig` to refresh shared library cache of a previously compiled and installed package to make it ready for a compile of a downstream package

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You have to distinguish between finding `so`'s at compile-time and at run-time. The `-L` flag you give at compile-time has nothing to do with localizing the library at run-time. This is rather done via a number of variables and some paths embedded in the library.

The best hot-fix for this problem is often setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the directory with the `.so` file, e.g.:

```
 $ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.. ./i2c
```

For a long-term solution, you need to either have a close look at the whole LD system with `rpath` and `runpath`, or use `libtool` (which solves these issues for your portably).

Copying a file to `/usr/local/lib` is often insufficient because `ld` caches the available libraries, so you need to re-run `ldconfig` (as root) after you copied a library to `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: Is LD_LIBRARY_PATH for all of my libraries? So if I do that command, it will mess up other things until I change it back? How do I see what it is set to now?

Comment: It's an environment variable. So you can check it via "echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH" and, the way it is set in the command line, is local to the i2c process and its subprocesses.

Comment: Not my question, but thanks this helped solve my exact problem

Answer (score 25):

If you are building the code from source that needs the the library, you can put the path that the library is in in the environment variable [LD_RUN_PATH](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options) before building, and the linker will save that path into the binary, so that it will automatically be looked for in the right place at runtime.

Linux specific: Alternately, put the library in `/lib`, `/usr/lib`, or some other path referenced in your `/etc/ld.so.conf` or its imported config fragments, and then all you need to do is run `/sbin/ldconfig` to refresh ld.so (the dynamic linker)'s cache of libraries.

Comment: Even though I had `/usr/local/lib` in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf`, the **dynamic link library cache refresh** with `sudo ldconfig` is what did it for me.

Answer (score 5):

This works for my issue,hope will help anyone.

```
gcc test.c -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib -lfcgi -o test.fcg
```

And `-Wl,-rpath` option is the key trick.